# Is there a way to run termux script from a android app?

Tags: java, android, node.js, termux, termux-linux

I got a Java android app that receive buffer of byte from a nodejs, i want to run script when you open the app like
cd backend
sudo node server.js
Is there a way?

Now i open termux and run script and then I open my app.
I didn't find anything to resolve my problem...

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/wiki/RUN_COMMAND-Intent)?